# Resultados inesperados al eliminar items mediante list.remove

Tags: python, lista

El problema es que tengo el siguiente código:

```
calificaciones = []

if len(calificaciones) == 0:
    print("No hay notas Disponibles", "\n")
else:
    numerodenota = int(input("cual nota desea cambiar"))
    nuevanota = float(input("ingrese la nueva nota"))
    calificaciones.insert(numerodenota, nuevanota)
    calificaciones.remove(numerodenota)
    print("las nuevas notas son : ", calificaciones, "\n")
```

y en el apartado de cambiar notas produce diferentes salidas al ejecutarlo, puede que salga un error en el rango, como que funcione perfectamente o se cambie la nota en la posición que no es.

Anteriormente esta la función para agregar las notas y después esta el `main`, así que por ello no hay problema, solo esa función es la que no da la misma salida cada vez que se ejecuta.

Comment: Si era eso, muchas gracias

Comment: No pongas solucionado a tu pregunta, para eso tienes la zona de respuestas donde va la explicación de lo que hiciste

Comment: @FJSevilla, suguiero que escribas una respuesta con el contenido de tu comentario. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate hecho, gracias por el aviso. Originalmente no lo hice porque quería aclarar que verdaderamente quería usar el índice en la lista para identificar la nota a reemplazar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en que has malentendido lo que hace el método `list.remove()`, esperas que elimine un item de la lista pasándole su índice en la misma, pero la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) nos dice (traducción libre):

> `list.remove(x)`
>   Remueve el primer item de la lista **cuyo valor es igual a x**. Lanza una excepción  `ValueError` si no existe tal item en la lista.

Esto hace que lógicamente tu salida sea "inconsistente":

- ```
  >>> calificaciones = [5, 8, 2, 6, 9]
  >>> calificaciones.insert(2, 4)
  >>> calificaciones.remove(2)
  >>> calificaciones
  [5, 8, 4, 6, 9]
  ```

  Parece que funciona, pero solo lo hace porque en el indice 2 hay un 2 y porque es el primer 2 en la lista.
- ```
  >>> calificaciones = [2, 8, 2, 6, 9]
  >>> calificaciones.insert(2, 4)
  >>> calificaciones.remove(2)
  >>> calificaciones
  [8, 4, 2, 6, 9]
  ```

  aquí tenemos el primer problema, `remove` elimina el primer 2 de la lista (índice 0) y no el item con índice 2.
- ```
  >>> calificaciones = [5, 8, 7, 6, 9]
  >>> calificaciones.insert(2, 4)
  >>> calificaciones.remove(2)

  Exception has occurred: ValueError
      list.remove(x): x not in list
  ```

  aquí tenemos una excepción directamente porque no hay ningún 2 en la lista...

Para eliminar un item de una lista por su índice usa `del`:

```
>>> calificaciones = [5, 8, 7, 6, 9]
>>> calificaciones.insert(2, 4)
>>> del calificaciones[3]  # list.insert inserta el elemento antes del índice dado
>>> calificaciones)
[5, 8, 4, 6, 9]
```

o si además de eliminar quieres obtener el elemento usa `list.pop(indice)`:

```
>>> calificaciones = [5, 8, 7, 6, 9]
>>> cal_eliminada = calificadiones.pop(2)
>>> cal_eliminadaca
7
```

En tu caso, dado que lo que quieres es simplemente reemplazar un elemento, dado que las listas son objetos mutables, solo reasigna usando el índice:

```
>>> calificaciones = [5, 8, 7, 6, 9]
>>> calificaciones[2] = 4
>>> calificaciones
[5, 8, 4, 6, 9]
```

En tu caso concreto deberías hacer algo así:

```
if not calificaciones:
    print("No hay notas Disponibles\n")

else:
    numero_de_nota = int(input("¿Cuál nota desea cambiar?: "))
    if  0 <= numero_de_nota < len(calificaciones):
        nueva_nota = float(input("Ingrese la nueva nota: "))
        calificaciones[numero_de_nota] = nueva_nota
        print(f"Las nuevas notas son: {calificaciones}\n")
    else:
        print("La nota no existe\n")
```

> **Nota**: para comprobar si una lista está vacía no uses `if len(lista) == 0`, usa simplemente `if not lista`.